# Integral $ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{T}A x \phantom{\times} \textrm{exp} \left( x^{T}Bx-\ln{x^{T}x} \right) dx, $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

I need help with this multiple integral

$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
x^{T}A x \phantom{\times}  \textrm{exp}  \left( x^{T}Bx-\ln{x^{T}x} \right) dx,
$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Following assumptions can be made:

- $A$ and $B$ is symmetric, negative definite and invertible
- One parameter of $x$ is constant (let's say $x_n = -1$)

Comment: Should the integral be over $\mathbb R^n$? Also, how are integrating over $x$ and one of the entries of $x$ is constant?

Comment: Note that $ exp(x^T B x - \ln x^T x) = \frac{exp(x^T B x)}{x^T X} $

Comment: This can probably be solved elegantly with the cylindrical coordinates $ \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty r dr \int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} f(r u) du$

Comment: $r^{n-1} dr$ not $r dr$

Comment: @JackT Yes, it can be integrated over $\mathbb{R^n}$. My study of the function showed, that the integral may diverge. In case of removing one degree of freedom $x^T=[\chi \phantom{\times} -1]$, $\chi \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, the integral converges under (semi) definitness assumption for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @phaedo I tried cylindrical coordinates for all parameters free and cylindrical coordinates for $x_n = -1$ (x_n was height). The problem is, that I was not able to solve the resulting trig hell. Also, this can be used only for specific number (assuming hyperspherical and hypercylindrical coordinates) of parameters and not generally for $n$.

Comment: Technically, if you fix a coordinate you are no longer integrating over $\Bbb R^n$ but over an affine hyperplane.

Comment: @blue indeed the condition $x_n = -1$ corresponds to a Radon transform $ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(x_n + 1) x^T A x e^{\cdots} dx$ where $\delta$ is Dirac's delta function...  The Fourier slice theorem might be another way to calculate

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer but here are some ideas:
$$
I = \int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} u^T A u \int_0^\infty r^{n-1} e^{-r^2\,u^T (-B) u} dr du
$$
Change of variable $r \mapsto r/\sqrt{u^T(-B) u}$:
$$
I = \int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} \frac{u^T A u}{(u^T (-B) u)^{n/2}} \int_0^\infty r^{n-1} e^{-r^2} dr du
$$
with $ \int_0^\infty r^{n-1} e^{-r^2} dr = \frac12 \Gamma(n/2) $.  From B symmetric there is an orthogonal matrix $\Omega$ such that $B = \Omega D \Omega^T$ where D is diagonal. If $\Omega$ is a rotation, the spherical integral is invariant (change of variable $u \mapsto \Omega u$):
$$
I = \frac12 \Gamma(n/2) \int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} \frac{u^T \Omega^T A \Omega u}{(u^T D u)^{n/2}} du
$$
Spectral decomposition of A might also help...  Unless I messed up this integral should converge without the condition $x_n = -1$.  Also, this problem looks like some weighted average of Rayleigh's quotient...